# html5 <video> tag; click anywhere js works everywhere but firefox

Tags: javascript, html, video

Firefox seems to add it’s own ‘click anywhere to play’ behavior, it dims the poster and adds a play button.  It works great, but the problem is that no other browsers seem to add that behavior automatically.  So, I’ve had to implement a javascript workaround to allow ‘click anywhere to play’ in other browsers.  They work great, but now it’s broken in firefox.  The way it behaves, it seems like the javascript I put in there is getting a click and making it play, but then ff’s own ‘click anywhere to play’ catches the click too, and pauses it immediately.  I can inch along the entire video, 1 or 2 seconds at a time, if keep clicking.  As for the specific js workarounds that I've tried, many of the examples from these two threads:
[How can I add click-to-play to my HTML5 videos without interfering with native controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880917/how-can-i-add-click-to-play-to-my-html5-videos-without-interfering-with-native-c)
and
[Click the poster image the HTML5 video plays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278262/click-the-poster-image-the-html5-video-plays)

I was really hoping for a `<video>` attribute like click-anywhere="yes", but I think I'm out of luck there.  Or, as a solution to my problem, something like the css: moz-click-anywhere:false; to allow the js to handle clicks exclusively.

The only solution I can think of is the browser detection route, but I’m hoping there’s a more elegant solution.  If not, so be it, but it was worth asking.

Comment: could you post a fiddle so we can see your script?